# How to reshape a polars dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I am new to polars, but have worked quite a bit with pandas and numpy. Let's say I have a dataframe df like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | W | B | 2 | X |
| C | 3 | Y | D | 4 | Z |

I would like to do something like df.reshape((-1,3)) (in numpy) in order to obtain:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | W |
| B | 2 | X |
| C | 3 | Y |
| D | 4 | Z |

however I haven't been able to find a similar function in polars. df.melt() doesn't work in this case of course and doing df = pl.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape((-1,3))) doesn't seem like an optimal solution. Would appreciate any help!

Looked through the documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think polars has a specialised `reshape` function for the scenario outlined above. However, you could combine [`pl.concat`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html) to concatenate dataframe fragments created using [`pl.DataFrame.select`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.select.html).

```py
pl.concat([
    df.select("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"),
    df.select(
        pl.col("Column 4").alias("Column 1"),
        pl.col("Column 5").alias("Column 2"),
        pl.col("Column 6").alias("Column 3"),
    ),
])
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column 1 ┆ Column 2 ┆ Column 3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ i64      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A        ┆ 1        ┆ W        │
│ C        ┆ 3        ┆ Y        │
│ B        ┆ 2        ┆ X        │
│ D        ┆ 4        ┆ Z        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`rename()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the columns and then [`concat()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) to vertically stack them together:

```py
pl.concat([
    df.select("Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"),
    df.select("Column 4","Column 5","Column 6")
    .rename({"Column 4":"Column 1", "Column 5":"Column 2", "Column 6":"Column 3"})
])

┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column 1 ┆ Column 2 ┆ Column 3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ i64      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A        ┆ 1        ┆ W        │
│ C        ┆ 3        ┆ Y        │
│ B        ┆ 2        ┆ X        │
│ D        ┆ 4        ┆ Z        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

To make it more generic, it's probably easier to pre-create list of columns / dictionary for renaming columns

```py
# define how do you want to split the columns
import numpy as np

# split the list of columns into 2 chunks
#
#[
#    ["Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"],
#    ["Column 4","Column 5","Column 6"]
#]
ncols = np.array_split(df.columns, 2)

# create a map to rename columns, which will look like
#
# {
#   'Column 4': 'Column 1',
#   'Column 5': 'Column 2',
#   'Column 6': 'Column 3'
# }
nmap = {k: v for x in ncols[1:] for v, k in zip(ncols[0], x)}

pl.concat(
    [df.select(cols).rename(lambda x: nmap[x] if x in nmap else x) for cols in ncols]
)

┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column 1 ┆ Column 2 ┆ Column 3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ i64      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A        ┆ 1        ┆ W        │
│ C        ┆ 3        ┆ Y        │
│ B        ┆ 2        ┆ X        │
│ D        ┆ 4        ┆ Z        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

With this solution you can decide how do you want to split your columns. For example, if you want to vertically stack 1,2 + 3,4 + 5,6 you can do it easily (given you have same type of the columns):

```py
...
ncols = np.array_split(df.columns, 3)
...

┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column 1 ┆ Column 2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ A        ┆ 1        │
│ C        ┆ 3        │
│ W        ┆ B        │
│ Y        ┆ D        │
│ 2        ┆ X        │
│ 4        ┆ Z        │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```